# Textview background repeats in a listview

Tags: android, listview, background, textview

So the problem that i am facing, is that when i try to set dynamically the background of a textView that belongs to a listView, the background that i set, is set for other textViews too..it repeats itself...i saw that these problems with listView items are common, but couldn't find a solution for me

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ViewHolder holder;

         if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_item, null);

             holder = new ViewHolder();

             holder.increment = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.increment);
             holder.decrement = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrement);
             holder.pic_view_quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic_view_quantity);

             convertView.setTag(holder);

         } else {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }



         holder.pic_view_quantity.setText(products.get(position).getQuantity());
         if (products.get(position).getQuantity().matches("[0-9]+")){
             holder.pic_view_quantity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_rectangle); //this is where i set the background, to items that have a quantity
         }

         return convertView;
     }
```

My layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
     android:layout_width="70dp"
     android:layout_height="70dp" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/pic_view"  
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/product_picture"  >

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/pic_view_quantity"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pic_view"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pic_view"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pic_view"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pic_view"
       android:layout_margin="1dp"
       android:textSize="36sp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textColor="#FF0000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `getView()` is run for every item in your `adapter` so you need to set a condition to only change the `background` of the items you want. Its hard to give an example without knowing your criteria but that's the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `else` to the following statement

```
if (products.get(position).getQuantity().matches("[0-9]+")){
    holder.pic_view_quantity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transparent_rectangle); //this is where i set the background, to items that have a quantity
}
else {
    holder.pic_view_quantity.setBackgroundResource(0); 
}
```

Comment: Views in an adapter are recycled, you have to have to tell it what to draw for both states (in your case if getQuantity matches OR IT DOESN'T) because it does not inflate it from your XML again. Think of your XML as one view that gets shown for all rows. You need to change the properties of that view for each row.

Comment: In other words `R.layout.product_item` is inflated once, and reused. If for one row, you change the background, you need to change it back in the next row if necessary.